# Show $e^x$ is irrational for rational $x \neq 0$

Tags: irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

I want to show that if $x$ is rational and nonzero then $e^x$ is irrational.

Clearly $e^{\frac{r}{s}} = \frac{p}{q} \Rightarrow q^s e^r = p^s$, but this doesn't seem helpful. The usual proof that $e$ is irrational doesn't look like it can be extended either.

Comment: You may want to utilize the Taylor Expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: a question with this already exists

Comment: You get $e^r=p^s/q^s$ which is a rational number by assumption. Note that this time, $r$ is an integer, and may even be assumed positive. So you're left with proving that $e^r$ is irrational for all _natural numbers_ $r$, instead of rational numbers $r$. That seems a bit less daunting to me.

Comment: See here page 27: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.167.5285&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: See [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Transcendence_of_e_and_.CF.80).

Comment: Hint: It suffices to show $e^n$ is irrational for all integer exponents $n\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

Knowning that $e$ is transcendental, the algebraic equation $q^sz^r-p^s=0$ cannot have $e$ as a root.

Comment: Yeah but how do you know $e$ is transcendental?  See Theorem 1 page 30 of this book.  They spend pages to prove this, so it can't be that easy: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.167.5285&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Transcendence of $e$ is taken for granted and we show that it implies the irrationality of $e^x$ for $x$ rational.

Comment: I don't see the transcendental assumption in the statement of the question.

Comment: So: maybe (?) the point of the question is that proving $e^x$ irrational for all rational $x$  is easier than proving $e$ transcendental.